# Input field in iframe is not scrollable on iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, input, iframe, scroll

Imagine iframe and input field inside of it. Imagine that the value of field is longer than inputs width, so the part of string in not visible. On iphone as a user I want to move caret to the end of string. But cursor stops next to the right border of input and string is not scrolling in the input. I see such problem in all text inputs inside iframes on iphone. There is no such problem on Android.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/28ls2.jpg)

Can I as a developer fix this issue? meybe some css solution?

I have tried to add overflow-x: scroll to the input but it didn't help.